# Scalar Product with Telescope Sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

I have a basic analysis problem that I don't manage to solve:

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly positive sequence with $a_n \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$ and $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence converging to $u\in \mathbb{R}$.

I wish to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k-1})u_k=u$$

What I observe is that $\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k-1})=1$. I tried to apply Hölder's inequality but got stuck.

Could anyone give me a hint how to approach the problem?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-a_{k-1})=1,
\end{equation}

thus

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-a_{k-1})u=u.
\end{equation}

Now, let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. There exists $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n>N_\epsilon$ we have $|u_n-u|<\epsilon$. We want to estimate

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-a_{k-1})(u_k-u),
\end{equation}

so let $M\in\mathbb{N}$ be large, in particular $M>N_\epsilon$. Then,

\begin{align}
|\frac{1}{a_M}\sum_{k=1}^{M}(a_k-a_{k-1})(u_k-u)|&< |\frac{1}{a_M}\sum_{k=1}^{N_\epsilon}(a_k-a_{k-1})(u_k-u)|+|\frac{1}{a_M}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon +1}^{M}(a_k-a_{k-1})(u_k-u)| \\
&<\frac{C}{a_M}+\epsilon |\frac{1}{a_M}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon +1}^{M}(a_k-a_{k-1})| \\
&<\frac{C}{a_M}+\frac{\epsilon}{a_M}|a_M-a_{N_\epsilon}| \\
&<\epsilon+\frac{C+\epsilon a_{N_\epsilon}}{a_M} \overset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} \epsilon
\end{align}

Edit: This is not exactly precise, but the idea should work.
Edit 2: Typos

Comment: Thank you! If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ now is a real sequence, could I prove using the just shown that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x_k}{a_k} < \infty \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k=0}^n x_k=0  $$?

Comment: Probably. You can define $u_k:=\frac{x_k}{a_k}$ and use the fact that the sum converges, to show $u_k\rightarrow 0$. Then if you use the formula above, you should probably be able to get it. You'll get two sums, the one you want to show is equal to zero and another with a ratio $\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_k}$. Not quite sure what to do about that one, but should be able to estimate it somehow.